# Unable to submit Internal Error - Chrome Store Extension Submission

Tags: google-chrome, store, submission

I have an extension that we have been updating for the last few years periodically. However when I tried to 'submit for review' an update for this chrome extension, the store is showing a popup 'Unable to submit Internal Error' popup. Has anyone faced similar issue, how was it resolved?

Comment: in-answer to your question: I just ran into this error as well when I tried to update my extension. I think it's an issue with the system, not your account or your extension. I haven't been able to find any other information, yet. Still searching.

Comment: I'm experiencing this for the past 10 hours.

Comment: Facing the same issue on publishing new extension.

Comment: Same here... since yesterday evening

Comment: Me too, yesterday no error but today it shows Internal error

Comment: Did anyone find a public announcement/explanation from Google about this?

Comment: Last time tried 18 hours ago.. And still same issue. "Unable to submit" , "internal error."

Comment: Same for me too. Unable to publish because of internal error.

Comment: I've experienced the same issue since June 25th PST afternoon

Comment: I had this error yesterday, but today I was able to submit.

Comment: I just tried again and submitted the extension successfully.